# How do variables behave when they're reinitialized in for loops?

Tags: c

When foo is called, it prints 42. I thought it would print 4. How do variables behave when they're reinitialized in for loops?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int x = 23;
void foo(void) {
    int i, x = 42;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        int x = 3;
        x += 1;
    }
    printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

Comment: Every pair of `{}` initializes a new block in C/C++. If you re-declare variables inside a new block, the newly declared variable will be used inside the block. If you just redefine the value inside a block, the variable outside the block will be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared `int x` several times in your code.  Each one of those declarations creates a separate variable.  Therefore, when you reference `x` anywhere, the rule is that you get access to the variable which is "closest" to your code.

That is, the line `x += 1` increases the value of the `x` variable declared inside the `for` loop (i.e., `int x = 3;`).  However, that variable only exists for each iteration of the loop.  That is, it is created anew every time a new iteration is run.

When you run `printf("%d\n", x);`, the `x` from the `for` loop no longer exists.  Instead, the `x` which was declared at the top of your `foo` function is used.

If you were to remove the re-declaration of `x` within your for loop, you'd see the behavior you expected.  I.e.,

```
for (i=0; i < 5; i++) {
    x = 3;
    x += 1;
}
```

Comment: I'd like to point out that the value of `x` in the end will be `8` here, since the loop will run 5 times. Not `4` as OP is expecting.